# HTTPS breaking font reference in IE and chrome

Tags: css, https, typekit

Check out https://www.hyperiontx.cbstage.com/ in IE and Chrome. The header tags (`h1` through `h6`) all have a fonts specification relying on a javascript fonts.com specification that isn't rendering properly, though it is rendering at the unsecured http address, at http://www.hyperiontx.cbstage.com. Check out the title that says "Our focus: saving..." and compare. What's going on?

Comment: Where do you declare the @font-face?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome's developer console has your answer.

> [blocked] The page at https://www.hyperiontx.com/ ran insecure content from http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/b3fca0c6-ff69-4fdb-b66b-8c298c1cd396.js.

Chrome is blocking the script that inserts the relevant font CSS because it's loaded insecurely.

Try changing the reference to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//fast.fonts.com/jsapi/b3fca0c6-ff69-4fdb-b66b-8c298c1cd396.js"></script>
```